# User login read from file failing compared to user input

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, user-input

I'm writing a program that will verify a username:

```
def user_login():
    """ Login and create a username, maybe """
    with open('username.txt', 'r') as f:
        if f.readline() is "":
            username = raw_input("First login, enter a username to use: ")
            with open('username.txt', 'a+') as user:
                user.write(username)
        else:
            login_id = raw_input("Enter username: ")
            if login_id == str(f.readline()):
                return True
            else:
                print "Invalid username."
                return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if user_login() is not True:
        print "Failed to verify"
```

Everytime I run this it outputs the following:

```
Enter username: tperkins91
Invalid username.
Failed to verify
```

How do I compare user input to reading from a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening the same file again in another nested context is not a good idea. Instead, open the file once in *append* mode, and use `f.seek(0)` to return to the start whenever you need to:

```
def user_login():
    """ Login and create a username, maybe """
    with open('username.txt', 'a+') as f:
        if f.readline() is "":
            username = raw_input("First login, enter a username to use: ")
            f.seek(0)
            f.write(username)
            # return True/False --> make the function return a bool in this branch
        else:
            login_id = raw_input("Enter username: ")
            f.seek(0)
            if login_id == f.readline():
                return True
            else:
                print "Invalid username."
                return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if user_login() is not True:
        print "Failed to verify"
```

Returning a bool value in the `if` branch is something you may want to consider so the return type of your function is consistent as bool, and not `None` as in the current case.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `readline()` the first time the current file position is moved past the first record.   A better way to find if the file is empty is to test it's size:

```
import os.path
import sys

def user_login():
    fname = 'username.txt'

    """ Login and create a username, maybe """
    if os.path.getsize(fname) == 0:

        with open(fname, 'w') as f:
            username = raw_input("First login, enter a username to use: ")
            f.write(username)
            return True    #/False --> make the function return a bool in this branch
    else:
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            login_id = raw_input("Enter username: ")
            if login_id == f.readline().rstrip():
                return True
            else:
                print >>sys.stderr, "Invalid username."
                return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if user_login() is not True:
        print "Failed to verify"
```

`f.readline()` will include a trailing newline, if there is one in the file, whereas `raw_input()` will not.  While we don't explicitly write one, someone might edit the file and add a newline unintentionally, hence the addition of the `rstrip()` as a defensive precaution.